# Kinect 2 with unity3d speed keep on when the player stopped but keep one knee up

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a running game that detect the player knee movement and add speed , its working fine but the problem is when I stop running and keep one knee up the game speed do not stop ,I need the speed to be decreased when I stop running even if one knee is still.

```
if (!player1)
    {
        player1 = GameObject.Find("player1");
        player1State.text = "";

    }
    if (player1)
    {
        player1FootRight = player1.transform.Find("KneeRight").gameObject;
        player1FootLeft = player1.transform.Find("KneeLeft").gameObject; 
        player1State.text = "OK";
        player1State.color = Color.white;

        newPosP1 = player1FootRight.transform.position.y;
        oldPosP1 = player1FootLeft.transform.position.y;


      if (startRunning) { 
        if (foot1 && newPosP1 > oldPosP1)
        {
            float k = newPosP1 - oldPosP1;
            if (k > 1 && speed < 100)
            {
                speed = speed + 7;
                if(leftPath.speed < 15)
                {
                    leftPath.speed = leftPath.speed + 3;
                }
                    footOld = foot1;
                    foot1 = !foot1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (speed > 0)
                {
                    speed = speed - 1;
                    if (leftPath.speed > 0)
                    {
                        leftPath.speed = leftPath.speed - 1;
                    }
                }
                if (speed < 0)
                {
                    speed = 0;
                }
                    if (leftPath.speed < 0)
                    {
                        leftPath.speed = 0;
                    }
                }

        }

        if (!foot1 && newPosP1 < oldPosP1)
        {
            float k = oldPosP1 - newPosP1;
            if (k > 1 && speed < 100)
            {
                speed = speed + 7 ;
                if (leftPath.speed < 15)
                {
                    leftPath.speed = leftPath.speed + 3;
                }
                    footOld = foot1;
                    foot1 = !foot1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (speed > 0)
                {
                    speed = speed - 1;
                    if (leftPath.speed > 0)
                    {
                        leftPath.speed = leftPath.speed - 1;
                    }
                }
                if (speed < 0)
                {
                    speed = 0;
                }
                if (leftPath.speed < 0)
                {
                    leftPath.speed = 0;
                }

            }

        }
```